# Grub2 insists on including zfs module when it does not exist

Tags: grub2

I'm creating a bootloader using `grub2-install`, it works fine but it keeps emitted this extraneous message:

```
  Booting `SUSE Linux Enterprise High Performance Computing 15 SP5'

Loading kernel ...
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:258:file `/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi/zfs.mod'
not found.
Loading initial ramdisk ...

Press any key to continue...
```

The message is non-fatal, but it's really annoying. The boot moves on if I wait a few seconds, or press any key. However it's fooling my users that the bootloader is not working.

I don't use ZFS on this system, why does Grub insist on loading the ZFS module?

Here's my code for creating my bootloader:

```
        # Add '--suse-enable-tpm' to grub2-install once we need TPM.
        grub2-install \
            --no-rs-codes \
            --suse-force-signed \
            --root-directory "${mpoint}" \
            --removable "$disk" \
            --themes=SLE \
            --locales="" \
            --fonts=""
```

Here are the available modules in the grub2 directory:

```
hypervisor:~ # ll /usr/share/grub2/x86_64-efi/
total 6759
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15384 Jul  6 10:10 acpi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1800 Jul  6 10:10 adler32.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8264 Jul  6 10:10 affs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8408 Jul  6 10:10 afs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2024 Jul  6 10:10 afsplitter.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23144 Jul  6 10:10 ahci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     680 Jul  6 10:10 all_video.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1360 Jul  6 10:10 aout.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   24776 Jul  6 10:10 appended_signature_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77224 Jul  6 10:10 appendedsig.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5192 Jul  6 10:10 appleldr.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4544 Jul  6 10:10 archelp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40552 Jul  6 10:10 asn1.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6648 Jul  6 10:10 at_keyboard.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9328 Jul  6 10:10 ata.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2432 Jul  6 10:10 backtrace.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9592 Jul  6 10:10 bfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3392 Jul  6 10:10 bitmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5736 Jul  6 10:10 bitmap_scale.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3080 Jul  6 10:10 blocklist.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3776 Jul  6 10:10 boot.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50464 Jul  6 10:10 bsd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3208 Jul  6 10:10 bswap_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   46216 Jul  6 10:10 btrfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2840 Jul  6 10:10 bufio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4352 Jul  6 10:10 cat.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5808 Jul  6 10:10 cbfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6088 Jul  6 10:10 cbls.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3944 Jul  6 10:10 cbmemc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1504 Jul  6 10:10 cbtable.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4416 Jul  6 10:10 cbtime.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15136 Jul  6 10:10 chain.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1464 Jul  6 10:10 cmdline.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4592 Jul  6 10:10 cmdline_cat_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2896 Jul  6 10:10 cmp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6440 Jul  6 10:10 cmp_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4021 Jul  6 10:10 command.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3496 Jul  6 10:10 configfile.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4344 Jul  6 10:10 cpio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4376 Jul  6 10:10 cpio_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2544 Jul  6 10:10 cpuid.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2064 Jul  6 10:10 crc64.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     936 Jul  6 10:10 crypto.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6976 Jul  6 10:10 crypto.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22296 Jul  6 10:10 cryptodisk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3984 Jul  6 10:10 cs5536.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2568 Jul  6 10:10 ctz_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3160 Jul  6 10:10 date.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2912 Jul  6 10:10 datehook.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3128 Jul  6 10:10 datetime.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3232 Jul  6 10:10 disk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17168 Jul  6 10:10 diskfilter.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1264 Jul  6 10:10 div.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8040 Jul  6 10:10 div_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2824 Jul  6 10:10 dm_nv.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2944 Jul  6 10:10 echo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13136 Jul  6 10:10 efi_gop.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7120 Jul  6 10:10 efi_uga.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2072 Jul  6 10:10 efifwsetup.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10520 Jul  6 10:10 efinet.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   25736 Jul  6 10:10 ehci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6592 Jul  6 10:10 elf.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2096 Jul  6 10:10 eval.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8712 Jul  6 10:10 exfat.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2160 Jul  6 10:10 exfctest.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9104 Jul  6 10:10 ext2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7976 Jul  6 10:10 extcmd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9992 Jul  6 10:10 f2fs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8808 Jul  6 10:10 fat.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Jul  6 10:10 fdt.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26848 Jul  6 10:10 file.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2952 Jul  6 10:10 fixvideo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18272 Jul  6 10:10 font.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     219 Jul  6 10:10 fs.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4656 Jul  6 10:10 fshelp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47040 Jul  6 10:10 functional_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2280 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_arcfour.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9008 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_blowfish.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   28440 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_camellia.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14744 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_cast5.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11776 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_crc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16832 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_des.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3296 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_dsa.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3896 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_idea.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4104 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_md4.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4528 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_md5.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3192 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_rfc2268.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20400 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_rijndael.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7824 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_rmd160.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3336 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_rsa.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13568 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_seed.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16808 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_serpent.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7744 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_sha1.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5424 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_sha256.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6664 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_sha512.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13472 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_tiger.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   33712 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_twofish.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22760 Jul  6 10:10 gcry_whirlpool.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8872 Jul  6 10:10 geli.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8496 Jul  6 10:10 gettext.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   61672 Jul  6 10:10 gfxmenu.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17160 Jul  6 10:10 gfxterm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4424 Jul  6 10:10 gfxterm_background.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7664 Jul  6 10:10 gfxterm_menu.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5424 Jul  6 10:10 gptsync.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1320960 Jul  6 10:20 grub-tpm.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1275904 Jul  6 10:20 grub.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12992 Jul  6 10:10 gzio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6608 Jul  6 10:10 halt.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8576 Jul  6 10:10 hashsum.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10400 Jul  6 10:10 hdparm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1760 Jul  6 10:10 hello.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3840 Jul  6 10:10 help.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4472 Jul  6 10:10 hexdump.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10280 Jul  6 10:10 hfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11464 Jul  6 10:10 hfsplus.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4296 Jul  6 10:10 hfspluscomp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9640 Jul  6 10:10 http.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4520 Jul  6 10:10 iorw.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12560 Jul  6 10:10 iso9660.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9256 Jul  6 10:10 jfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10552 Jul  6 10:10 jpeg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5064 Jul  6 10:10 json.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1236944 Jul  6 10:10 kernel.exec
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  119728 Jul  6 10:10 kernel.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6656 Jul  6 10:10 keylayouts.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3088 Jul  6 10:10 keystatus.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8408 Jul  6 10:10 ldm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15816 Jul  6 10:10 legacy_password_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   45768 Jul  6 10:10 legacycfg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18024 Jul  6 10:10 linux.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8912 Jul  6 10:10 linux16.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     672 Jul  6 10:10 linuxefi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4728 Jul  6 10:10 loadbios.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9760 Jul  6 10:10 loadenv.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4960 Jul  6 10:10 loopback.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6368 Jul  6 10:10 ls.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7008 Jul  6 10:10 lsacpi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5184 Jul  6 10:10 lsefi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3568 Jul  6 10:10 lsefimmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4616 Jul  6 10:10 lsefisystab.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2832 Jul  6 10:10 lsmmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7096 Jul  6 10:10 lspci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3704 Jul  6 10:10 lssal.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6192 Jul  6 10:10 luks.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20976 Jul  6 10:10 luks2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12120 Jul  6 10:10 lvm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6768 Jul  6 10:10 lzopio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5112 Jul  6 10:10 macbless.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12448 Jul  6 10:10 macho.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2736 Jul  6 10:10 mdraid09.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2768 Jul  6 10:10 mdraid09_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2648 Jul  6 10:10 mdraid1x.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3168 Jul  6 10:10 memdisk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4536 Jul  6 10:10 memrw.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5928 Jul  6 10:10 minicmd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5864 Jul  6 10:10 minix.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5952 Jul  6 10:10 minix2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6032 Jul  6 10:10 minix2_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5984 Jul  6 10:10 minix3.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6064 Jul  6 10:10 minix3_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5936 Jul  6 10:10 minix_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9992 Jul  6 10:10 mmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5334 Jul  6 10:10 moddep.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2601 Jul  6 10:10 modinfo.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3280 Jul  6 10:10 morse.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   42944 Jul  6 10:10 mpi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3728 Jul  6 10:10 msdospart.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2328 Jul  6 10:10 mul_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22776 Jul  6 10:10 multiboot.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   25848 Jul  6 10:10 multiboot2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7008 Jul  6 10:10 nativedisk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  135536 Jul  6 10:10 net.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4544 Jul  6 10:10 newc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10184 Jul  6 10:10 nilfs2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176608 Jul  6 10:10 normal.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16112 Jul  6 10:10 ntfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5792 Jul  6 10:10 ntfscomp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4344 Jul  6 10:10 odc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2128 Jul  6 10:10 offsetio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15992 Jul  6 10:10 ohci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2296 Jul  6 10:10 part_acorn.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2608 Jul  6 10:10 part_amiga.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2976 Jul  6 10:10 part_apple.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4256 Jul  6 10:10 part_bsd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2624 Jul  6 10:10 part_dfly.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2208 Jul  6 10:10 part_dvh.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3264 Jul  6 10:10 part_gpt.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3008 Jul  6 10:10 part_msdos.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2472 Jul  6 10:10 part_plan.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2272 Jul  6 10:10 part_sun.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2504 Jul  6 10:10 part_sunpc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     111 Jul  6 10:10 partmap.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      17 Jul  6 10:10 parttool.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7792 Jul  6 10:10 parttool.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2960 Jul  6 10:10 password.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4616 Jul  6 10:10 password_pbkdf2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7912 Jul  6 10:10 pata.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1880 Jul  6 10:10 pbkdf2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3320 Jul  6 10:10 pbkdf2_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3568 Jul  6 10:10 pcidump.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20240 Jul  6 10:10 pgp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1536 Jul  6 10:10 pkcs1_v15.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4296 Jul  6 10:10 play.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11304 Jul  6 10:10 png.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2584 Jul  6 10:10 priority_queue.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5592 Jul  6 10:10 probe.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3792 Jul  6 10:10 procfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3000 Jul  6 10:10 progress.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1872 Jul  6 10:10 raid5rec.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3232 Jul  6 10:10 raid6rec.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3640 Jul  6 10:10 random.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3064 Jul  6 10:10 rdmsr.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3280 Jul  6 10:10 read.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1520 Jul  6 10:10 reboot.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76568 Jul  6 10:10 regexp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14032 Jul  6 10:10 reiserfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26736 Jul  6 10:10 relocator.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5760 Jul  6 10:10 romfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7176 Jul  6 10:10 scsi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5576 Jul  6 10:10 search.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4752 Jul  6 10:10 search_fs_file.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4856 Jul  6 10:10 search_fs_uuid.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4808 Jul  6 10:10 search_label.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14936 Jul  6 10:10 serial.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     912 Jul  6 10:10 setjmp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2520 Jul  6 10:10 setjmp_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8408 Jul  6 10:10 setpci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7992 Jul  6 10:10 sfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2992 Jul  6 10:10 shift_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8640 Jul  6 10:10 signature_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3328 Jul  6 10:10 sleep.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3224 Jul  6 10:10 sleep_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8768 Jul  6 10:10 smbios.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3096 Jul  6 10:10 spkmodem.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10320 Jul  6 10:10 squash4.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3160 Jul  6 10:10 strtoull_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30888 Jul  6 10:10 syslinuxcfg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5208 Jul  6 10:10 tar.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     162 Jul  6 10:10 terminal.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6824 Jul  6 10:10 terminal.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19048 Jul  6 10:10 terminfo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7472 Jul  6 10:10 test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51984 Jul  6 10:10 test_asn1.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2032 Jul  6 10:10 test_blockarg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3888 Jul  6 10:10 testload.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3432 Jul  6 10:10 testspeed.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    7728 Jul  6 10:10 tftp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6568 Jul  6 10:10 tga.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2384 Jul  6 10:10 time.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8208 Jul  6 10:10 tpm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38208 Jul  6 10:10 tpm2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3632 Jul  6 10:10 tr.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1936 Jul  6 10:10 trig.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1864 Jul  6 10:10 true.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13200 Jul  6 10:10 udf.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8000 Jul  6 10:10 ufs1.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8160 Jul  6 10:10 ufs1_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8000 Jul  6 10:10 ufs2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10072 Jul  6 10:10 uhci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15896 Jul  6 10:10 usb.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5856 Jul  6 10:10 usb_keyboard.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11128 Jul  6 10:10 usbms.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2832 Jul  6 10:10 usbserial_common.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3416 Jul  6 10:10 usbserial_ftdi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3776 Jul  6 10:10 usbserial_pl2303.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2240 Jul  6 10:10 usbserial_usbdebug.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5448 Jul  6 10:10 usbtest.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      16 Jul  6 10:10 video.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9944 Jul  6 10:10 video.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10104 Jul  6 10:10 video_colors.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   28368 Jul  6 10:10 video_fb.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5288 Jul  6 10:10 videoinfo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5432 Jul  6 10:10 videotest.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3672 Jul  6 10:10 videotest_checksum.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2448 Jul  6 10:10 wrmsr.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10960 Jul  6 10:10 xfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   43912 Jul  6 10:10 xnu.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3256 Jul  6 10:10 xnu_uuid.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3176 Jul  6 10:10 xnu_uuid_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19832 Jul  6 10:10 xzio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   79304 Jul  6 10:10 zstd.mod
```